Trying to use Beautifulsoup4 in Python via an venv and getting 'ModuleNotFoundError' when using VSCode
I am facing a rather minor problem where I am unable to use the Library 'Beautifulsoup4'. I use VSCode as IDE and use a Venv with Python Version 3.12.2. Everytime I try to run my programm it gives me the error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

To import Beautifoulsoup I use the import command, which even gets recognized and suggested, when trying to type it, by the IDE:
import bs4

At first I have successfully activated my venv in the terminal via:
.venv/scripts/activate

Then I have tried to install the Library via Pip:
pip install beautifulsoup4          

and
pip3 install beautifulsoup4         

After trying to install it via pip I was able to find the Library inside the folder of the "Lib" folder of the venv. But it still did not work. I have tried to uninstall and reinstall it multiple times but it was still not working.
I have already check and see that I was using the right interpreter and I was.

Hello, if the library is downloaded under the interpreter of your choice. You can try using from bs4 import BeautifulSoup to import. Just like the answer describes, see if that solves the problem.

Hello @Jeanneli ,  I have mentioned in the post that I have already tried that. It did not work for me. I have already tried selecting every interpreter and looked into the library folders of the interpreter and saw that the library was installed for the interpreter instance. I believe that this may be a problem with my IDE but I cannot tell. When doing the exactly the same on a cloud server it seems to work but it does not work when trying it on my Home Computer when using VSCode.

Hello, maybe you can try clearing vscode's cache, then recreate the environment and download it. See if this solves the problem.

Hello @Jeanneli ,  I have finally managed to fix this issue. It somehow occurred later with every new Library that I wanted to install. I have managed to fix this problem by deleting everything, clearing the cache and then reinstalling every package that I had uninstalled. Somehow trying to just clearing the cache didn't work. Thanks you very much for your help!

BeautifulSoup is a class of bs4 so you are doing wrong directly installing BeautifulSoup. First you have to install bs4 with requests then have to import BeautifulSoup from bs4 like below
pip3 install bs4 requests

and then use
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



Seems like VSCode is trying to run the default python interpreter installed on your system (where package beautifulsoup4 is not installed) instead of particular venv (where you have already installed this package). To tell VSCode to use the particular venv set the python.defaultInterpreterPath option in your .vscode/settings.json file - see Manually specify an interpreter
Seems like package beautifulsoup4 should be imported as bs4 according to "Quick start" section - from bs4 import ..

P.S. I always set one another option -python.terminal.activateEnvironment - for having venv activated in VSCode terminals too.
